# Mysql join selects multiple column best practice

Tags: mysql, join, laravel-query-builder

I'm using **Laravel Query Builder**  and my join statement working perfectly.

**`User`** table columns:

```
name|email|phone|gender
```

**`School_Abouts`** table columns:

```
courses|boards|contact|location|teachers
```

Currently I do the *select* query as below:

```
$school=User::join('school_abouts', 'users.id', '=', 'school_abouts.school_id')
                ->where('users.id',$id)
                ->select('users.name',
                        'users.email',
                        'users.phone',
                        'school_abouts.courses',
                        'school_abouts.boards',
                        'school_abouts.contact',
                        'school_abouts.location',
                        'school_abouts.teachers')
                ->first();
```

To select the columns from **`school_about`** table I have to write table name multiple times. But is there any way to pass an array of columns instead? I tried this but failed:

```
->select('users.name',
   'users.email',
   'users.phone',
   'school_abouts'.[courses,boards,location,contact,teachers],
)
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Are you sure that's the same structure of `School_Abouts`? Since none of the columns within your query exists in it.

Comment: Columns are for demo only.

Comment: You showed us `School_Abouts`'s structure for a reason. Didn't you?

Comment: Got your point. now have a look on question.

Comment: In fact, you can safely remove preceding table name off column. As they are unique in each table.

Comment: That's worked for me. What if `columns` are not unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely remove table name from columns as there is no column name common in both tables but else, as I see, you are trying to get almost all columns from both tables which could be simplified using `*`:

```
$school = User::join('school_abouts', 'users.id', '=', 'school_abouts.school_id')
                ->where('users.id', $id)
                ->select('users.*', 'school_abouts.*')
                ->first();
```

However, if you want to get some columns and their names could make an ambiguity then prefixing column names with table name is a must. To make it shorter you could use aliasing:

```
$school = User::join('school_abouts AS sa', 'users.id', '=', 'sa.school_id')
                ->where('users.id', $id)
                ->select('users.name',
                        'sa.courses',
                        'sa.boards',
                        'sa.contact',
                        'sa.location')
                ->first();
```